# Manage API to create forests in all nodes in a group in a clustered environment

Tags: marklogic

In the cluster there are two groups e-node and d-node. Both are having 3-3 hosts.
Is there a manage API which will allow me to create forests in all the nodes in the specific group. 
In this case let's say in d-node group.

I want to configure the number of forests per host also.

Comment: While you can use the Manage API to do this, mlgradle might be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure if there is an endpoint that will do that automatically for you, but you can certainly get it done.

You could read the list of groups available with a GET on the groups endpoint:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/groups

Drilling down into each group of interest will tell you which hosts are inside each of them:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/groups/[id-or-name]

And then you use a POST to the forests Management API endpoint to create forests on targeted hosts:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/forests

To finish off, you'd have to attach forests to databases as needed:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties

Alternatively, you might be able to create and attach all forests at once using the latest Configuration Management API:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v3

HTH!